# cron job error: sh: 1: <pkg>: not found

Tags: python, django, cron

I am using coverage module for my python django project. Now I want to mail my coverage report using cron job. for that purpose I create script for run unit test cases and send report in attachment. which is working fine if i am running that file manually. but using cron job I am getting this error while taking log in logfile.

```
sh: 1: coverage: not found
```

My file for run unit test and send mail:
**coverage_report.py**

```
def run_test():
    print 'before running'
    try:
        print commands.getoutput("cd project_path && coverage run --source='.' manage.py test")
    except:
        print "Error in run_test"
    print 'done running'

def generate_report():
    try:
        commands.getoutput('cd /tmp/ && rm report.txt')
        commands.getoutput('cd project_path && coverage report */*.py >> /tmp/report.txt')
    except:
        print "Error in generate report"
def send_mail():
    send_email('Coverage Report', 'This is coverage report for this week ', ['gauravnagpal2002@gmail.com'],'plain',['/tmp/report.txt'])


def main():
    run_test()
    generate_report()
    send_mail()
    print "Mail send successfully."

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

If I run this file manually Its working fine and send the report in txt format. but If i am running this file using cron job its sending the blank file.
my corn job syntax:

```
21  6  *  *  *  python <project_path>/scripts/coverage_report.py >> /tmp/coverage_report.log
```

The file generated after running this file **/tmp/coverage_report.log**

```
before running

sh: 1: coverage: not found
done running
Mail send successfully.
```

Please Help.

Comment: ``PATH`` problem. ``coverage`` is not in Cron's path. YOur shell script **should** include a ``export PATH=...`` in your script.

Comment: @JamesMills Thanks for you comment I got the solution. Yes path was the problem. I am giving now full path of coverage i.e /usr/local/bin/coverage rather than coverage. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` problem.

`coverage` is not in your cron job's path.

Your shell script should include a:

```
export PATH=...
```